# How to change "parse_cli_textfsm" to reference template folder in role folder in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-filter

### **GOAL**

- I want to create a portable role folder that utilizes textfsm templates in role directory.
- Directory structure

```
$ tree
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts.ini
├── out_pb1
├── pb1.yml
├── roles
│   ├── command_facts
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── textfsm   // I want this
│   │   └── vars
└── templates
    └── textfsm   // created for testing
```

### **PROBLEM**

- `parse_cli_textfsm` is referencing to `templates/textfsm` instead of `roles/command_facts/templates/textfsm`
- The goal is portability so specifying full path is not considered.

### **ATTEMPTS TO FIX (FAIL)**

- Executes `pb1.yml`
- Error shown as below if I deleted `templates/textfsm` in the `pb1.yml` directory.

```
$ ansible-playbook pb1.yml -u username -k
(omitted)
TASK [command_facts : set_fact]
fatal: [target]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to locate parse_cli_textfsm template: /templates/textfsm"}
```

- I tried to utilize system variable `role_path` that is `{{ raw_output.stdout | parse_cli_textfsm('{{ role_path }}/templates/textfsm') }}` but it is not working. `{{ role_path }}` turns into a normal string.

```
$ ansible-playbook pb1.yml -u username -k
(omitted)
TASK [ixrs_facts : set_fact] 
fatal: [target]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to locate parse_cli_textfsm template: {{ role_path }}/templates/textfsm"}
```

### **FILES**

- `roles/command_facts/task/main.yml`

```
---
- name: show protocols all
  raw: "show protocols all"
  register: raw_output
- set_fact:
    output: {{ raw_output.stdout | parse_cli_textfsm("/templates/textfsm") }}
- debug: var=output[::]
```

- `pb1.yml`

```
---
- name: testing
  hosts: target
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - { role: command_facts }
```

### **REFERENCE**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#network-cli-filters
- `{{ output.stdout[0] | parse_cli_textfsm('path/to/fsm') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
`parse_cli_textfsm('{{ role_path +“/templates/textfsm“) }}`